# Move Zeroes to the end of the string

Tags: python, list

I was just doing some leetcode
but this blew my mind.

```
class Solution:
  def moveZeroes(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:
    nums = [0, 1, 0, 3 ,12]
    k = 0
    i=0
    while i < len(nums):
        print(i)
        if nums[i] == 0:
            print('inside if=',i)
            print('before',nums)
            k += 1
            print('removed',nums[i])
            nums.remove(i)
            print('after',nums)
        else:
            i += 1
            print('no change',nums)
    print('final',nums)
    for j in range (k):
        nums.append(0)
    print(nums)
```

and the output is:

```
0
inside if= 0
before [0, 1, 0, 3, 12]
element to be removed 0
after [1, 0, 3, 12]
0
no change [1, 0, 3, 12]
->1
->inside if= 1
->before [1, 0, 3, 12]
->element to be removed 0
->after [0, 3, 12]
1
no change [0, 3, 12]
2
no change [0, 3, 12]
final [0, 3, 12]
[0, 3, 12, 0, 0]
```

How can it remove element 1 if it can read that it has to remove 0?

Comment: `nums.remove(i)` does not remove `nums[i]`. It removes the value `i` from your list.

Comment: More specifically, it removes the first item from `nums` whose value is equal to `i`.

Comment: Advice - try to pick a good Algorithm book and study it.  `"Leetcode" `is not the best place to learn coding .... just my .02 cents.

Comment: thank you. BTW used pop() so it solved

Answer (score 0):

So I got to know my dumb mistake.
Actually `remove()` is used to remove the element that is mentioned.
Like if I type `remove(6)`from a list  `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. it removes element 6, not the element that is at 6th position.
so use `pop()` to do so.